# Setting an alias with attributes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I wanted to set an alias for listing files in the directory, but `Set-Alias -name lf -value ls -file` does not seem to work. I intend to use this the Unix alias way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An alias can't do that. From the help for `Set-Alias`:

> You can create an alias for a cmdlet, but you cannot create an alias for a command that consists of a cmdlet and its parameters.

However, using a technique called "splatting", a function can do it easily:

```
function lf {
  ls -file @args
}
```

For more information, see `help about_splatting`.

Comment: List all command: `function la { ls -attr ReadOnly,Hidden,System,Dir,Arch,Dev,Norm,Tempor,Sparse,Reparse,Compre,Offline,NotContentInd,Encryp,Integr,NoScrub @args }`

Answer (score 0):

Example 5 from `Get-Help Set-Alias -Full` is what you want:

```
Function lsfile {Get-Childitem -file}
Set-Alias lf lsfile
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but the problem is that I cannot extend by giving additional arguments; say `lsfile -recurse` will fail

Comment: Then I think @mike has the best option.  Create a function, and add that to your profile.  It will end up just like an alias for all intended purposes, but you can pass more arguments to it.

Answer (score 0):

Append to the answer from @mike-z .

You can put the function definition into the PowerShell profile so that you can reuse it opening shell again.

```
test-path $profile
// Ensure it doesn't exists before creating the profile!
new-item -path $profile -itemtype file -force
notepad $profile
```

Simply put the code into the file:

```
function lf { ls -file @args }
```

You can check the details from [official documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx%20%E2%80%9CWindows%20PowerShell%20Profiles%E2%80%9D).